# Lebesgue Integrable function and non singular transformations

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, linear-transformations

Suppose T∈GL(n,R) and T is non singular. If f is a Lebesgue measurable function on Rn, so is f∘T. If f≥0 or f is integrable with respect to the n-dimensional Lebesgue meseaure, then
∫f(x)dx=|detT|∫f∘T(x)dx. Kindly help me to prove this

Comment: My immediate guess is to prove something similar for sets. Then, it would be true for simple functions, nonnegative functions, and integrable ones.

Comment: Yeah, I will try to prove in this way

Comment: The set of $T$ for which it holds is a subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$. Therefore you only need to prove the theorem for transformations that generate $GL$. Also, for fixed $T$, it is enough to show it in the case where $f$ is the indicator of a rectangle.